# Will adding a NONCLUSTERED INDEX as suggested by DTA improve performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008, indexing

I have the following tables defined in the database

**Shop Table**

- ShopId
- ShopName
- Owner
- Banner
- Header
- CityId
- ShopImageId
- Active

**City Table**

- CityId
- CityName
- CountryId
- RegionId

**Country Table**

- CountryId
- CountryName
- RegionId

**REGION**

- RegionId
- RegionName

**ShopImages**

- Id
- Image
- ShopId

Here is my select query

```
SELECT ShopName, Owner, CityName, CountryName,RegionName
FROM Shop S 
INNER JOIN City CT ON CT.CityId=S.CityId
INNER JOIN Country CO ON CO.CountryId=CT.CountryId
INNER JOIN Region R ON CT.RegionId=R.RegionId
LEFT OUTER JOIN ShopImages SI ON S.ShopImageId=SI.Id

WHERE S.Banner like '%restaurant%' OR S.Description like '%restaurant%'
AND S.CityId=10 AND S.Active=1
```

> As of now city table has around 3,000,000 records & Shop has
>   40,000,000 + records.

***It takes time to fetch records. All the clustered indexes(primary key) were already defined.***

> I am trying to optimize with the help of DTA(Database Tuning Advisor).
>   It suggest me to add the below index

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX 
  [_dta_index_CITY_9_2098106515__K9_K20_K1_K2] ON [dbo].[CITY] 
(
    [COUNTRYID] ASC,
    [REGIONID] ASC,
    [CITYID] ASC,
    [CITYNAME] ASC
)WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF) 
  ON [PRIMARY]
```

Is it worth to add this Index? Can i take all the suggesstion from DTA? It suggesting adding some statistics also.

How better how can improve my above query ?

Comment: `INNER JOIN Region R ON Region.RegionId=R.RegionId`? Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Thanks for it. I updated now. Typo mistake :)

Comment: Still, I would have assumed `INNER JOIN Region R ON CT.RegionId=R.RegionId` :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, seems like CT stands for CITY and it dont have RegionId mapped. Only Country has mapped. So he is correct!

Comment: @Murali Yes, I was just surprised that DTA suggested an index including CITY.REGIONID if it's not even in the query.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, OMG. Thanks. To avoid long question, I removed many columns. :( Now updated

Comment: @BadDeveloper, Big question is not problem, detailed information will be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say that DTA is *wrong* when analyzing the indexes, since I do't know the data distribution and it does, but the first indexes I'd add beyond the primary keys is a (possibly composite) index on `SHOP.CityID` and `SHOP.Active`.

I can't give you any absolutes without testing, but this is the reasoning.

Since you're basically doing the filtering on `SHOP` and have no filters on any other table, the heavy lifting of the query would most likely be on filtering the 50M rows in `SHOP`.

If the database started joining from any other table, the unfiltered join would result in 3M rows against `CITY`, and starting with filtering `SHOP` would most likely result in quite a bit fewer. The compiler likes "fewer" for good reason.

This is the filter on `SHOP`;

```
WHERE S.Banner like '%restaurant%' OR S.Description like '%restaurant%'
  AND S.CityId=10 AND S.Active=1
```

Since `LIKE` queries starting with `%` basically *can't use indexes at all*, you'll want as narrow and quick filtering as possible done by `S.CityId=10 AND S.Active=1`. If you index those, the other two conditions won't need to scan more than a few rows found using the indexes instead of scanning - possibly - 50M rows.

The only reason I can see that the index suggested would make more than a minor impact is if the `CITY` table has a large amount of fields, and the index would allow the database to read less data from disk to get to the fields. Not saying it's the case, but only trying it will tell for sure.

Comment: Nice. Wonderting how come the DTA is not suggesting this :) It just suggests me CREATE STATISTICS [_dta_stat_1250103494_8_19] ON [dbo].[Shop]([ACTIVE], [CITYID])

Comment: Will adding index on [ACTIVE], [CITYID] impact any other issues in other queries they not using this combination in WHERE Clause?

Comment: I think the opposite order (ie, [CityId], [Active]) would be much preferrable, if Active is even worthwhile at all.(With only two possible values it's not necessarily that helpful, possibly depending on the distribution)

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, If i write my WHERE Clause S.Active=1 AND  S.CityId=10 , then the order will be Active & City right?

Comment: The order things are written in the query is not really relevant. My general reasoning was that the filtering by CityId will probably eliminate much more stuff than the filtering by Active. (But again, I don't know your distribution, so I'm guessing.)

Comment: @BadDeveloper The index should (as Håkan is saying) most likely be `(CityID, Active)` to be more selective (CityID) at the first lookup.

Comment: @BadDeveloper  The order in which you order the conditions in the query should (with a reasonable optimizer) be irrelevant, the RDBMS will normally choose a condition that results in the fewest rows using the least effort (usually involving an index). Choosing the correct "path" is what it uses statistics for.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist, The most important consideration when defining a concatenated index is how to choose the column order so it can support as many SQL queries as possible. This is from http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

Comment: Good to see the order impact. I like :)

Comment: @BadDeveloper My main point is that Active probably isn't a great candidate for an index in the first place (as I noted, you may even want to just skip it entirely). Based on this, to me it seems much more useful to be able utilize the index for when filtering by CityId only than by Active only.

Comment: @BadDeveloper If there is no "natural" order to the columns in the index (ie one of them is always included in queries), you'll probably get a better over all effect not composing the index at all but creating two separate indexes. If most shops are active, you should consider (as was said above) if the effect is big enough to create the index on `Active` at all.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I got it. Most of the time i search against Active shops. There will be most no of records indicates Active, assuming 8/10. In this case, I think CityId,Active would make sense. What is your suggestion? Have a composite in an order CityId, Active or only on CityId or both?

Comment: @BadDeveloper My suggestion (yes, still practical testing beats estimating) is that if you mostly query on both and never just on Active without CityId, use a composite `(CityId, Active)`, otherwise separate indexes on the columns. I can't really see a big gain in `(Active, CityId)` with only 20% inactive.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to reconsider having the clustered indexes on the primary key columns in some cases.

If for instance you typically search for shops in a given city (which would be the case if the example query is "the typical query"), it may be very beneficial to have Shop clustered on CityId (so that all shops in a given city are grouped together)

Comment: I already have the clustered index created for ShopId, as it is a primary key. I think sql server will automatically create clustered index on ShopId.

Comment: Yes, that was my impression from what you wrote. What I am saying is that you may want to reconsider this. (You can make the index on ShopId non-clustered and create a clustered one on CityId if that better suits your requirements.)

Comment: I have other queries like WHERE ShopId=5 for fetching only Shop Item, which not including City. I hope having clustered on ShopId make sense. Share your thoughts please :)

Comment: I am saying that I think it probably doesn't make sense. Looking up a unique value like that doesn't benefit from the column having a clustered index the way that your other query being able to find all the shops with the same CityId would benefit.